# How to set chartJs Doughnut labels on right side?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Actually i'm using chart js [chartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/other-charts/doughnut.html) Doughnut chart, this is working fine but how can I set chartJs Doughnut labels on right side?

**My Code:-**

```js
   const countryChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('countryChart').getContext('2d'), {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: ['India', 'Netherlands', 'UAE', 'Egypt', 'Others'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Revenue',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }],
            },
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="countryChart" height="150"></canvas>
```

I want like this:-
[image]

ThankYou for your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for it, We need to just add legend positions as given below answer:-

You can also follow given URL to know more about ChartJs positions:-
[click here to know more](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/legend/position.html)

```
options: {
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'right'
                }
            }
        }
```

```js
const countryChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('countryChart').getContext('2d'), {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: ['India', 'Netherlands', 'UAE', 'Egypt', 'Others'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Revenue',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }],
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        position: 'right'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="countryChart" height="150"></canvas>
```